# After update lifecyle to version 2.4.0 Make build error AAR metadata file: **/aar-metadata.properties

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

After update lifecycle version to 2.4.0 i cant build my app the error code is :

```
One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: **/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0.
AAR metadata file: **/transformed/jetified-lifecycle-livedata-ktx-2.4.0/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

added this code but its not work for me

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change  compileSdk to 31 and targetSdk 31

if use AGP 7.* or above

```
android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdk 30
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

if use AGP Below 7

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
   
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdkVersion 30
        ...
    }
}
```